# Is there a way to restart a cursor? Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to do something such as:

```
for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j<10; j++)
    {
        Blah;
    }
}

//As you can see each time that there is a different i, j starts at 0 again.
```

Using cursors in Oracle. But if I'm correct, after I fetch all rows from a cursor, it will not restart. Is there a way to do this?

Here is my sql:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SSACHDEV.SyncTeleappWithClientinfo
as
teleCase NUMBER;

CURSOR TeleAppCursor
is
    Select 
        distinct(casenbr)
    from TeleApp;


CURSOR ClientInfoCursor
is
    Select casenbr 
    from clientinfo 
    where trim(cashwithappyn) is null;

BEGIN

    open TeleAppCursor;
    open ClientInfoCursor;

    LOOP
        fetch TeleAppCursor into teleCase;
        EXIT when TeleAppCursor%NOTFOUND;

        LOOP
            fetch ClientInfoCursor into clientCase;
            EXIT when ClientInfoCursor%NOTFOUND;
                if clientCase = teleCase then

                    update ClientInfo 
                    set cashwithappyn = (select cashwithappyn from teleapp where casenbr = clientCase) 
                    where casenbr = clientCase;

                    break;
                end if;
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;

END;
```

I did check online and was unable to find anything on this.

Comment: First, why does "restart" mean to you and why do you need to "restart"?  The pseudo-code you posted of what you're trying to accomplish doesn't appear to require a restart.  Second, why do you want to write nested loops in PL/SQL?  SQL is a set-based language-- it will be much more efficient (not to mention much less code) to write a single `UPDATE` statement that updates every row that you want to update rather than coding two loops and issuing tons of `UPDATE` statements that each update just one row.

Comment: By restart I mean start at the top of the results table again.

I need to enter the data (cashwithappyn) of 1st table into the 2nd table, only if the caseNumber is the same, and only if the 2nd table cashwithappyn is null.

Comment: I guess, closing the cursor and then re-opening it again would restart the cursor. But , I still agree with Justin, why do you want to do all that you did in your code? It could be done in a more simple way.

Comment: I've never really worked with Oracle before this project.

Comment: Closing and re-opening the cursor will return the results again.  However, the results may be different the second time around (assuming this is a multi-user system and you have not set the transaction isolation level to serializable).  And you'll incur the costs of executing the query a second time.  If your data volumes are small, you could potentially fetch the data from the cursor into a local collection that you iterate through multiple times (though I'm still not seeing why you would need to re-process a row).  But the most efficient approach is a single SQL statement.

Comment: Would this take care of the entire query?

    update ClientInfo set cashwithappyn = (select cashwithappyn from teleapp where casenbr = clientCase) where CLIENTINFO.CASENBR = TELEAPP.CASENBR and trim(cashwithappyn) is null;

Comment: Assuming that casenbr is unique in TeleApp, you could:  update ClientInfo 
set cashwithappyn = (select cashwithappyn from teleapp where casenbr = clientCase AND CLIENTINFO.CASENBR = TELEAPP.CASENBR ) 
WHERE trim(cashwithappyn) is null;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the second cursor at all, just use the set operations in Oracle to update the appropriate records without manually searching for them yourself:

```
DECLARE
    v_teleCase      TeleApp.teleCase%TYPE;
    v_cashwithappyn TeleApp.cashwithappyn%TYPE

    CURSOR TeleAppCursor
    is
        Select 
            distinct casenbr, cashwithappyn
        from TeleApp;

BEGIN

    open TeleAppCursor;

    LOOP
        fetch TeleAppCursor into v_teleCase, v_cashwithappyn;
        EXIT when TeleAppCursor%NOTFOUND;

        UPDATE ClientInfo
        SET cashwithappyn = v_cashwithappyn
        WHERE casenbr = v_teleCase
        AND trim(cashwithappyn) is null;

    END LOOP;

END;
```

It's also a good idea to not have variables with the same name as columns.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of restarting the Cursor you could use a table variable to store the results of sql statement and then loop over the table an arbitrary number of times.

Here's an example using the SQL Fiddle Sample data.

```
DECLARE 
    CURSOR c1 IS 
      SELECT id, 
             TYPE, 
             details 
      FROM   supportcontacts; 

    TYPE contactrec 
      IS TABLE OF c1%ROWTYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER; 

    acontact    c1%ROWTYPE; 
    contactlist CONTACTREC; 
    counter     INTEGER; 
BEGIN 
    counter := 0; 

    OPEN c1; 

    LOOP 
        FETCH c1 INTO acontact; 

        IF c1%FOUND THEN 
          counter := counter + 1; 
        END IF; 

        Contactlist(counter) := acontact; 

        IF c1%NOTFOUND THEN 
          EXIT; 
        END IF; 
    END LOOP; 

    CLOSE c1; 



    FOR i IN 1..5 LOOP 
        FOR j IN 1..counter LOOP 
            dbms_output.Put_line(Contactlist(j).type  || ' ' || Contactlist(j).details); 
        END LOOP; 
    END LOOP; 
END; 

/
```

which outputs

```
Email admin@sqlfiddle.com
Twitter @sqlfiddle
Email admin@sqlfiddle.com
Twitter @sqlfiddle
Email admin@sqlfiddle.com
Twitter @sqlfiddle
Email admin@sqlfiddle.com
Twitter @sqlfiddle
Email admin@sqlfiddle.com
Twitter @sqlfiddle
```

Here's the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ee7da/1624) but I can't figure out how to see the output from dbms_output

Comment: to see the output you first need to:  SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

Comment: @kurosch In SQL Fiddle? Can you share a link with it working because when [I tried](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/2856) that I get `ORA-00922: missing or invalid option : SET SERVEROUTPUT ON`

Comment: I've never used SQL Fiddle, I do not know what options they support.

Comment: Ah. That's what I referring to when I said I can't see the output